# Notation question from differential geometry and PDE

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, notation

Let Greek indices denote indices that range over $0,1,\dots,d$. I'm looking at $\mathbb R^d \times \mathbb R$ (here I'm looking at *the wave equation*, so there are space and time indices). Let $g$ be a function. What do the notations $\partial^\alpha g \partial_\alpha g$ and $\partial_\beta g\partial^\beta g$ mean and how are they different? I know that the repeated indices means that you are summing over all values of the indices, so $\partial^\alpha g \partial_\alpha g = \sum_{\alpha=0}^d \partial^\alpha g \partial_\alpha g$ and similarly $\partial_\beta g\partial^\beta g = \sum_{\beta=0}^d \partial_\beta g\partial^\beta g$. But what is the difference between these two? It has something to do with the Minkowski metric.

One of these is probably $-g_t^2 + |\nabla g|^2$, but what is the other one?

Comment: Can you also provide the reference that you are reading?

Comment: You can raise or lower indexes using the metrics. So ti your metrix is $g_{\alpha\beta}$ you can say that $g_{\alpha \beta} h^{\beta} = h_{\alpha}$ and $h^{\alpha} = h_{\beta}g^{\alpha \beta}$ where $(g_{\alpha\beta})$ is the metrics and $(g^{\alpha\beta})$ is its inverse matrix. As $g$ stands for a metric I am using $f$ for what you call $g$. I think $\partial^{\alpha} f \partial_{\alpha}f$ stands for $g^{\alpha \beta}\partial_{\beta}f\partial_{\alpha}f$.

Comment: So $\partial^\alpha f\partial_\alpha f$ is defined to be $g^{\alpha\beta}\partial_\beta f\partial_\alpha f$. Is there more to this definition (like why it was made), or is this nothing but the conventional notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically $\partial^\beta$ are the components of the dual vector to $\partial_\beta$. In Minkowski space the sum $\partial_\beta g\partial^\beta g$ is indeed $-g_t^2 + |\nabla g|^2$.

And because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are dummy variables the two sums $\partial_\beta g\partial^\beta g$ and $\partial^\alpha g\partial_\alpha g$ are the same, the product of functions is commutative.

When we talk about the dual of $\partial_\beta$ we mean as follows:
Let's say that we are given a smooth manifold of dimension n, if we look at the tangent space of a point p in the manifold we can prove that it is isomorphic to the derivation space which is spanned by $\partial_\beta$ therefore we can treat the tangent space as the vector space spanned by $\partial_\beta$ which has dimension n.
For this vector space we can define the dual space as in linear algebra which is spanned by $\partial^\beta$ which satisfy $\partial^\alpha(\partial_\beta) = \delta^\alpha{}_\beta$.
If you have a metric g (or a pseudo metric as in general relativity), which means the tangent space is an inner product space, then the components of dual vectors are related by the formula: 
$$v_\alpha=g_{\alpha\beta} v^\beta, v^\alpha=g^{\alpha\beta} v_\beta$$
where subscript components are for the dual vector and superscript for the vector in the tangent space.

Comment: Can you explain more about dual vectors?   And DIdier_ above commented on a definition. How should I view that definition?

Comment: Posted an edit with explanations